# Marklogic API to get the reindex status of databases

Tags: marklogic, reindex

Hi please help me in getting the reindex status of databases using marklogic API. Right now we are using some thing like this:
let $forest-reports :=

```
            let $forest-reports :=
                for $forest-id in xdmp:database-forests($db-id) return
                xdmp:forest-counts($forest-id, "*")

            return 
            fn:sum(
                for $e in $forest-reports//*[fn:contains(fn:local-name(.), "reindex") and fn:contains(fn:local-name(.), "count")] 
                    where xs:integer($e) gt 0 
                    return xs:integer($e)
            )
        return
            if ($forest-reports) then
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Forest</b></td>
                        <td><b>Fragments to Reindex</b></td>
                    </tr>
                {
                <tr><td colspan="2"><b>{$forest-reports}</b></td></tr>
```

}

But sometimes this is not giving us the correct status.

Please let us know if we are following the correct way or not.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [xdmp:forest-status()](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:forest-status), for instance like this:

```
(
  for $forest-id in xdmp:database-forests(xdmp:database())
  return xdmp:forest-status($forest-id)//*:reindexing
) = fn:true()
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tested this snippet on the DB's which has reindex set to "true" but it is giving me the incorrect value

Comment: @aravind-babu: Can you elaborate on what would be an 'incorrect value'? The mere fact of having reindex set to true is no reason for the database to be reindexes continuously. Reindex is usually only necessary when indexes have changed. Adding new/updated documents to indexes is part of commit.